# Rails admin object rendering as `#<User:` in the index list view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

My model function:

```
def admin_user
  users.where('roles @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]', ['admin']).first
end
```

My admin configuration:

```
config.model 'Team' do
  list do
    field :admin_user
  end
end
```

It shows up like this:

[image]

How can I make it link to the User admin view?

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This is rails admin, I don't use a view @nabi

Comment: You need to add your view code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it shows `#<User:0x0....>` is because your `admin_user` returns an instance of ActiveRecord. When RailsAdmin outputs it calls its `#to_s` method, which, by default returns that output above. You can either override that method to look something like this:

```
# User class

def to_s
  name
end
```

or you could modify your `admin_user` to return a properly formatted string instead of ActiveRecord if you prefer.

In order to 'make it link to the User admin view' a bit more configuration is required in your `config.model`. You need to define a `pretty_value` for it and override default rendering.

```
config.model 'Team' do
   pretty_value do
     # user's active record
     user = bindings[:object]
     # path to its RailsAdmin 'show' page
     path = bindings[:view].show_path(model_name: 'User', id: bindings[:object].id)
     # <a href...> tag to it
     bindings[:view].tag(:a, href: path) << user.admin_user
  end
end
```

remember that `user.admin_user` in the last line assumes it returns a string that you want in your link or `User` that has a properly defined `#to_s`.

Here is a link to the official documentation https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-list-fields-as-HTML-tags

Comment: I had that problem when I did enum field. You solution worked but needed to change the list line to this      bindings[:view].tag(:a, {href: path}, true) << user.admin_user

Answer (score 0):

There´s another way
You can create another model

class AdminUser < User
    def self.default_scope
      where('roles @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]', ['admin'])
    end

```
after_initialize do
   self.roles << ['admin']
end
```

end

And then on the team model
class Team
    belongs_to :admin_user, foreign_key: :user_id

```
rails_admin do
  list do
    field :admin_user
  end
end
```

end

And this will not only show the right content on the Team index, but it will allow you to filter and search the teams through attributes of the admin, like name or email, also it will also allow you to create Admins with its own index and edit view. 
It might be a bit overkill but it will definitely solve your problem too.